# iBooks Author Latex Question

Tags: latex, ibooks-author

Any idea how would you go about drawing a 3x3 matrix in iBooks Author?

My Latex formula which works on other platforms is

$$\left[\begin{array}{ c c c }1 & 1 & 1 \2 & -1 & 1 \ 1 & 2 & -1\end{array} \right]$$

iBooks simply says "invalid equation".

Cheers

Nick

Answer (score 1):

iBooks Author only supports a subset of LaTeX, see [iBooks Author: About LaTeX and MathML support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501) for a full list of supported commands.

From looking at the samples in the support document, something like

```
\begin{matrix}
1 &  1 &  1 \\
2 & -1 &  1 \\
1 &  2 & -1 \\
\end{matrix}
```

should work.